# In Slick 3.0, why could `result` method be applied to a `Query` object?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick, typesafe

I'm using Slick 3.0: https://github.com/slick/slick/tree/3.0.0

The example codes looks like this:

```
class Coffees(tag: Tag) extends Table[(String, Double)](tag, "COFFEES") {
  def name = column[String]("COF_NAME", O.PrimaryKey)
  def price = column[Double]("PRICE")
  def * = (name, price)
}
val coffees = TableQuery[Coffees]
val coffeeNames: Future[Seq[Double]] = db.run(
  coffees.map(_.price).result
)
```

I think the `result` method in `coffees.map(_.price).result` is described here:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.5/index.html#scala.collection.mutable.Builder@result():To

which is a method of `Builder` class.

However, `coffees.map(_.price)` is a `Query` class instead of `Builder` class, and `Query` class seems not a subclass of `Builder` class. Moreover, there seems no implicit conversion from `Query` class to `Builder` class. And `Query` class doesn't have a method called `result`.

So how does the `result` be applied to the `Query` object. Does anyone have ideas about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `result` method is not from Builder class. It is defined in `QueryActionExtensionMethodsImpl` class in [JdbcActionComponent.scala](https://github.com/slick/slick/blob/3.0/slick/src/main/scala/slick/driver/JdbcActionComponent.scala) file.

Answer (score 0):

In /slick/profile/BasicProfile.scala,

```
  trait API extends CommonAPI with CommonImplicits {
    implicit def repQueryActionExtensionMethods[U](rep: Rep[U]): QueryActionExtensionMethods[U, NoStream] =
      createQueryActionExtensionMethods[U, NoStream](queryCompiler.run(rep.toNode).tree, ())
    implicit def streamableQueryActionExtensionMethods[U, C[_]](q: Query[_,U, C]): StreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[C[U], U] =
      createStreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[C[U], U](queryCompiler.run(q.toNode).tree, ())
    implicit def runnableCompiledQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU](c: RunnableCompiled[_, RU]): QueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, NoStream] =
      createQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, NoStream](c.compiledQuery, c.param)
    implicit def streamableCompiledQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, EU](c: StreamableCompiled[_, RU, EU]): StreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, EU] =
      createStreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, EU](c.compiledQuery, c.param)
    // Applying a CompiledFunction always results in only a RunnableCompiled, not a StreamableCompiled, so we need this:
    implicit def runnableStreamableCompiledQueryActionExtensionMethods[R, RU, EU, C[_]](c: RunnableCompiled[Query[R, EU, C], RU]): StreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, EU] =
      createStreamingQueryActionExtensionMethods[RU, EU](c.compiledQuery, c.param)
    // This only works on Scala 2.11 due to SI-3346:
    implicit def recordQueryActionExtensionMethods[M, R](q: M)(implicit shape: Shape[_ <: FlatShapeLevel, M, R, _]): QueryActionExtensionMethods[R, NoStream] =
      createQueryActionExtensionMethods[R, NoStream](queryCompiler.run(shape.toNode(q)).tree, ())
  }
```

There is a method called `repQueryActionExtensionMethods` which converts `Rep` (superclass of `Query`) into `QueryActionExtensionMethods`